# Replacing WMI calls with Winapi

Tags: python, windows, winapi, python-2.7, wmi

I am currently looking to replace all my code that uses WMI with equivalent win32 api calls. I am doing this because i have noticed that WMI calls take *much* longer to perform than win32 api calls. Some examples can be seen below:

**Listing services:**

- wmi: ~4 seconds
- winapi: ~0.003 seconds

**Listing Printers:**

- wmi: ~0.5 seconds
- winapi: ~0.009 seconds

**Listing Windows Users:**

- wmi: ~0.5 seconds
- winapi: ~0.2 seconds

Is it possible to replace all wmi calls? As a general rule, is every task available in WMI possible to perform with winapi calls?

I have already managed to replace most of my wmi code but i have the following left:

- Creating Restore Points
- Enumerating network adapters
- Enumerating partitions

I am having some difficulty with enumerating network adapters in particular.

Its also worth mentioning that i am using python (2.7) to perform all these calls (using ctypes, windll and win32 api libraries such as win32net, win32service etc...).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q**: Is it possible to replace all wmi calls?

**A**: Most of the WMI queries can be replaced with WinAPI methods, with a few exceptions.

**Q**: As a general rule, is every task available in WMI possible to perform with winapi calls?

**A**: No, not all the WMI classes have WinAPI equivalents. For example, the IIS related tasks only can be performed using the [IIS WMI Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525265%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). Also, there are no WinAPI methods to **enumerate** the restore points, and so on.

For you pending tasks you can use these WinAPI methods:

- Creating Restore Points - [System Restore Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- Enumerating network adapters - [`GetAdaptersInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function
- Enumerating partitions - use the [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method with the [IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365174%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control code

Comment: Regarding Network adapters: You should also take a look at [network List Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370803); but this is COM. See also [Using Network List Manager](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/574446/Using-Network-List-Manager-Cplusplus)